# Twilio - How to gather the key from receiver end ( called person)?

Tags: twilio

I am unable to find the answer in Twilio docs about how to gather the key inputs from receiver end. For example, I have web client which will dial to person ( say receptionist). Now I would like to take actions based on receptionist's input. How would I gather the keys from receptionist ( call receiver end ) ?

I have tried few combination with "Dial" and "Gather" verbs but it didn't work. 
Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can get your requirement done using '**Gather**' itself.

Have a look at this:

Use one or more of these attributes in a  verb like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" finishOnKey="*">
        <Say>Please enter your pin number and then press star.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

Comment: This will not work. As I need to dial the person first. And then need to gather the input from called person.

Answer (score 0):

Zack with Twilio Support here. Use the REST API to make a call or use a helper library.

Here's the documentation for making a call with the REST API and some samples:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

When you make the call, you'll specify the `To` number, the `From` number, and a `Url` to the TwiML you want to be executed when the recipient answers the call.

As the Murali mentioned, you'll need to use `<Gather>` to accept the digits pressed by the recipient of the call.

So the URL you specify in your call should return TwiML something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="http://somedomain.com/capture-digits">
        <Say>Please enter your some digits.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Any digits the recipient presses will be POSTed as a callback to your server. The URL you specify in the `action` attribute is where we will post those details.

Here's the full documentation and examples for using `<Gather>`:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

If you need further assistance, please contact us here:
https://www.twilio.com/help/contact

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone I have to build browser soft phone where Guest will press a button and talk to the Receptionist. We are using Twilio Client on browser side and <Dial> verb to call to Receptionist. Now we need to read the input keys pressed by Receptionist.  Can we build same scenario using REST API than using Twilio Client for the web soft phone ?  Thanks

Comment: Hi @MishitPatel, as long as the Receptionist is pressing the buttons before being connected to the caller, you should be able to accommodate that, but you can't gather pressed keys from the REST API. You have to use TwiML <Gather>. We'd be happy to walk you through that. Please contact us at https://www.twilio.com/help/contact so we can follow up easier with your questions. Thanks!